# MySQL: get a stored procedure to exit early on warning

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that runs a sequence of commands:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE foo
BEGIN
   A;
   B;
   C;
   D;
   E;
END//
```

I'd like to detect if any warnings are generated by command `D`, and, if so, cease execution (don't do command `E`).

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, but seems to clear the warnings, which isn't great:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE foo
BEGIN
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLWARNING
    SET @exiting=1 -- any statement will work here
  ;

  A;
  B;
  C;
  D;
END//
```

Comment: `RESIGNAL` to preserve the warnings

Comment: @dadykhoff could you example it?

Answer (score 4):

You can give your procedure a label name and call the LEAVE command on that label from the code.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE foo
myLabelName:BEGIN
   A;
   B;
   C;
   D; 
   If D is null
     Then Select 'Exiting at D';
     LEAVE myLabelName;
   End If
   E;
END//
```

Comment: ok, that's how I leave, but how do I tell whether command D generated warnings?

Comment: Depends on what you're doing for that step. You can create a boolean flag to track whatever it is that's gone wrong. What are you expecting to fail?

Comment: I'm using LOAD DATA INFILE, and want to quit if any rows generated warnings.

Comment: You're probably going to want to use a handler for the process here. It's the "try/catch" in MYSQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/declare-handler.html